# Jest mocking for enum in named export component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have the following child component:

```
export enum Bar { Yes = "Yes", No = "No" };

export const Child = () => {
    return <div>Something</div>
}
```

The parent component that I'm testing imports the `enum` in child:

```
export const Parent = () => {
    return Bar.Yes ? <Child /> : <div>Something else</div>
}
```

In my test for Parent, I'm mocking Child as:

```
jest.mock("path/to/child", () => ({
    Child: "child-component"
    __esModule: true,
}))
```

But when I go to write/run the test, it says `Bar.Yes` is undefined

I think the issue is that I'm mocking Child as `child-component` and that has no reference to the `enum`.

How do I mock it properly?

Answer (score 3):

Try moving the enum definition up to the parent. Generally you should move declarations up to a common parent, when they're used in multiple components.

Comment: Good idea, this is what I ended up doing. But it would still be helpful to know how this scenario can be handled in test.